# How can I read Less variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, webpack-2

How can I read **less variables** in javascript like [less-vars-to-js](https://github.com/michaeltaranto/less-vars-to-js)?

I'm working on a React project(webpack2、less etc), but not SSR(node environment)，so I can't use `fs` or `node-glob` module.

Some people suggest me writting a webpack loader myself :( i'm not really familiar with that... And I already used less-loader...

### javascript

```
import lessToJs from 'less-vars-to-js';
import styles from './style.less';

const jsStyle = lessToJs(styles); => Uncaught TypeError: sheet.match is not a function

const mycomponent = (
  <MyComponent
    className={styles.nav}
    tintColor={jsStyle['@tint-color']}
  />
);
```

### less

```
@import "../../../themes/theme.web.less";

@tint-color: grey;

.nav {
  background-color: @tint-color;
}
```

### webpack

```
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.less$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    { loader: 'style-loader' },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
      },
    },
    { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
    { loader: 'less-loader' },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Under normal circumstances, the LESS will have been compiled to CSS before being sent to the browser, at which point the LESS variables no longer exist, so you can't read them.

Comment: Implement a custom webpack loader that extracts variables from less files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment you could implement custom loader. Something like this (haven't tested)

```
//utils/less-var-loader.js
const lessToJs = require('less-vars-to-js')

module.exports = function(content) {
  return `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(lessToJs(content))}`
}
```

and then

```
import * as styles from '!!./utils/less-var-loader!./style.less'
```

Double bang `!!` to ignore preconfigured loaders.